# Redirect Route with statement in Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

in my methode I have the following route statement

```
return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Request is send!');
```

Now, I want to have this in my ajax success function. At the moment I am using this and I correctly redirect to 'home' but my with success message is not running.

```
$.ajax({
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/home/grouprequest',
                    data: {'groupid': groupid},
                    success: function (result) {
                        window.location.replace('/home'->with('success', 'Request is send!')); 
                    }
```

What I have to change?

Comment: can you add `grouprequest` action code ?

Comment: `'/home'->with('success', 'Request is send!')` - it's incorrect code. `window.location.replasce` - js function. try to send post through the html form.

Comment: Try this: _location.reload(true);_ instead of _window.location.replace_